# Keras.predict always gives "1."as the output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a binary classifier distinguish clear MNIST images from blurry images. All images are 28*28*1 grayscale digits and I have 40000 for training, 10000 for validating and 8000 for testing. My code looks like:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
from PIL import Image

img_width, img_height = 28, 28#all MNIST images are of size (28*28)

train_data_dir = '/Binary Classifier/data/train'#train directory generated by train_cla
validation_data_dir = '/Binary Classifier/data/val'#validation directory generated by val_cla
train_samples = 40000
validation_samples = 10000
epochs = 20
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 1)

#build a sequential model to train data
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(#train data generator
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)#validation data generator

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(#train generator
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',color_mode = 'grayscale')

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(#validation generator
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',color_mode = 'grayscale')

model.fit_generator(#fit the generator to train and validate the model
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_samples // batch_size)

#model.save_weights('output.h5')#save the output as HDF5 file
filelist = glob.glob('/Binary Classifier/data/image_data/*.png')
x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist])
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=3)
ones=model.predict(x)
```

But my output prediction in ones[] are all [1.] while the accuracy in training is actually really high(almost perfect). Does anyone know why?

Edit: I think I may get more help if I can show my image data. Basically the MNIST image in the directory is either a [image: clear digit](clear) or a [image: blurry digit](blurry). All are (28*28*1) grayscale images whose format is .png. There are 40000 digits in `'/Binary Classifier/data/train'` for training, 10000 digits in `'/Binary Classifier/data/val'` for validation and 58000 digits in `'/Binary Classifier/data/image_data/` for testing.

Comment: You probably have some issue with your target. Also, I can't see where you define it.

Comment: It's at the forth last row. What I do is basically importing all my image data, converting them to numpy arrays and predicting the output using the trained model.

Comment: I think you should look at the data ou are importing. If you get high accuracy, this means that your target contains mainly ones.  There is no problem with the neural network.

Comment: @Ahmed Lahlou Mimi Are you referring to the testing data or the validation data?

Comment: Perhaps you should post the structure of /Binary Classifier/data/train and /Binary Classifier/data/val and how many files there are under each subdirectory.

Comment: @D.J.Duff I just edited my question and will appreciate it if you can help

Comment: What is the subdirectory structure? What are the directories directly inside train/ and inside val/?

Comment: Both train/ and val/ have two subdirectories: clr/ for clear digits and blr/ for blurry digits.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Pull data directly from one of your generators and test on that. Treat the generator like you would a list in a for loop to get image/label pairs out. This should sort out any differences in the way you are obtaining data and its formatting (e.g. channel order).
- Check how many examples you have in each subdirectory of train/ and val/.
- Change your metric to `binary_accuracy` since you are posing the problem as a binary classification problem (network only has one output).